# why gradle build convert java file encoding

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, encoding, spring-security

here i'm using IntelliJ Idea compiling spring security source code and met a really agonizing question, every time i convert my current file encoding to 'UTF-8' and after for a while, maybe 1~2 minutes, and such file encoding became 'IOS-8859-1' and chinese character became messy. I have taken below steps to solve this question:

- add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` line into `idea64.exe.vmoptions` and `idea.exe.vmoptions` files
- change single file encoding to 'UTF-8' below right hand in Intellij Idea footer part.
- go to `setting` --> `File encoding` --> `convert each opened file to UTF-8`

all methods had tried and character became OK but while run `gradle build -x test`, such file became `IOS-8859-1` automatically which i can see right below in Idea. Maybe it's result from Gradle, but i have configure my gradle project CompileJava encoding and charset 'UTF-8', here is the configuration:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Hope anybody who can help me solve such question, thanks in advance!